# how to count number of unique string in a column per row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, count

I have this table

```
no    type
1     123, 234, 345
2     123
3     4567,235
4
```

I want to count number of strings in column `type` for each row, so I want to add new column in which shows the count result. The expected result would be:

```
no    type                 count
1     123, 234, 345          3
2     123                    1
3     4567,235               2
4     NaN                    0
```

how can I get the expected result by using pandas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try `str.count`:

```
df['count'] = df['type'].str.count(',').add(1).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   no           type  count
0   1  123, 234, 345    3.0
1   2            123    1.0
2   3       4567,235    2.0
3   4           None    0.0
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but the way above count the single entry as 0. How to fix it?

Comment: I don't get it, it matches your expected output?

Comment: I mean for row no 2 where it only has 1 string, the code counts it as 0

Comment: It shows `1` in my output. Did you forget `add(1)`?

Comment: I also include add(1)  on my script, but it gives me 0. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df['new'] = df['type'].str.split(',').str.len()
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension might be faster, depending on the data size:

```py
 df.assign(count = [len(ent.split(',')) 
                    if ent else 0 
                    for ent in df.type.fillna('')]
             )

   no           type  count
0   1  123, 234, 345      3
1   2            123      1
2   3       4567,235      2
3   4           None      0
```

Another option, in terms of speed, could be to convert to an ArrowString Dtype before applying Pandas' string methods.